# Pixel value differences in image downloaded through STAC api & Sentinel hub api

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-hub, stac

I downloaded same tile from [AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2-l2a-cogs/) & Sentinel API. I compared pixel values for both and they differ by 1000.
For example, consider red band.
The value at 0,0 (row,column) for the image from Sentinel 2 is say 2242, then for same pixel the value for image from AWS is 1242.
Why is this difference?
From AWS & Sentinel API, I am downloading S2L2A product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you are downloading a Sentinel 2 product published after January 2022. This is due to [Sentinel 2 Processing Baseline](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/-/copernicus-sentinel-2-major-products-upgrade-upcoming) breaking changes.

Sentinel Hub harmonizes data across multiple different Sentinel 2 Processing Baselines when users pick the default settings. This is so the changes like this don't affect users' existing processing pipelines.

You can find more about it in [documentation](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-2-l1c/#harmonize-values) and [a forum post](https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/sentinel-2-processing-baseline-changes-and-harmonizevalues/4635).